# Remove rows in data.table according to another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` named `dtA`:

My actual `dtA` has 62871932 rows and 3 columns:

```
  date    company    value
198101          A        1
198101          A        2
198101          B        5
198102          A        2
198102          B        5
198102          B        6
```

`data.table` `dtB` have some columns I want to remove from `dtA`, so `dtB` is like the rules:

Actual `dtB` has 19615280 rows and 3 columns:

```
  date    company    value
198101          A        2
198102          B        5
```

End result is:

```
  date    company    value
198101          A        1
198101          B        5
198102          A        2
198102          B        6
```

It is not as simple as:

```
dtA=dtA[!(dtB$company %in% dtA$company)]
```

because it also depends on date and value.

I tried to merge two tables together and chain it with not in statement:

```
dtA=dtA[dtB, on=date][!(company %in% comapny) & !(value %in% value)]
```

I get this message:

> Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical
>   limit). Very likely misspecified join.

Any ideas?

Comment: You expected data does not look correct. `198101          B        5` should have been removed.

Comment: no, dtB does not have 198101  B   5 but 198102 B 5 so the expected result is correct..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an anti-join:

```
dtA[!dtB, on=.(date, company, value)]
```

This matches all records in `dtA` that are not found in `dtB` using the columns in `on`.

Comment: Thanks it works! Nice and clean! My method is faster but coding is more clumsy

Comment: Hi, thank you for this answer. Could you confirm to me that here the use of `on=...` works only if the column names of both table match each other. In the case it wouldn't, it would need to setkey on both table, and therefor wouldn't need the call of the `on` parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know how to solve this:

in dtB I add a pointer using data.table syntax:

```
dtB[, pointer := 1]
```

dtB will looks like this

```
  date    company    value    pointer
198101          A        2          1
198102          B        5          1
```

Then I use LEFT OUTER JOIN method from here:
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html

```
setkey(dtA, date, company, value)
setkey(dtB, date, company, value)
dtA=merge(dtA, dtB, all.x)
```

This means on pointer column, if dtB's row exist in dtA, it will give 1. If dtB's row do not exist in dtA's, then it will be given NA

Result will be:

```
  date    company    value    pointer
198101          A        1         NA
198101          A        2          1
198101          B        5         NA
198102          A        2         NA
198102          B        5          1
198102          B        6         NA
```

I then select those rows with NA and remove pointer column:

```
dtA=dtA[!(pointer %in% "1")][,-c("pointer")]
```

I get my result:

```
  date    company    value
198101          A        1
198101          B        5
198102          A        2
198102          B        6
```